# Some characters are called evil for not encodeing

Tags: vb.net, encoding

I am writing a program to get data from a Html file, but my problem is that badly written characters that are received in Farsi.

In other languages:
Some characters are called evil for not encodeing
For example, the
The
���� � ����� ������

my code is :

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1

   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
       OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
       Dim pfile As String
       pfile = OpenFileDialog1.FileName.ToString
       Dim a As System.Text.Encoding
       a = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8 '' I used other encoding Such as default assci windows-1257 and ... but not fix!!
       Dim k_reader As New StreamReader(pfile.ToString, a)
       RichTextBox1.Text = k_reader.ReadToEnd

   End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly you guessed at the encoding wrong, it is not utf8.  Easy to see when you look at the actual HTML file:

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1256">
```

So fix the Encoding you use:

```
  a = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1256)
```

Comment: The content-type meta tag often lies about the document's encoding, though. You also have to check the `content-type` response header - edit: nevermind, he's reading an HTML file from disk.

Comment: +1 Thank you very much dear professor
I ask God to grant you health and longevity